# Resistor network calculations

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am trying to come up with formulas to get resistor values for the following circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flConF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The requirements are as follows:

- V<sub>3</sub> should be the same (2.5V) for two states, V<sub>1H</sub> (30V), V<sub>2L</sub> (0.05V); and V<sub>1L</sub> (29V), V<sub>2H</sub> (4.95V).
- I<sub>1</sub> should not exceed 200uA in a first state.

I've used branch current method analysis to come up with some formulas that seem to be valid regardless of I<sub>3</sub> direction

V<sub>1</sub>(R<sub>4</sub>/R<sub>1</sub>) + V<sub>2</sub>(1 + R<sub>3</sub>/R<sub>1</sub> + R<sub>3</sub>/R<sub>2</sub>) - V<sub>3</sub>(1 + R<sub>3</sub>/R<sub>1</sub> + R<sub>4</sub>/R<sub>1</sub> + R<sub>3</sub>/R<sub>2</sub> + R<sub>4</sub>/R<sub>2</sub>) = 0

R<sub>3</sub> = (CR<sub>4</sub> - R<sub>1</sub>) / (1 + R<sub>1</sub>/R<sub>2</sub>); Where C = (V<sub>1H</sub> - V<sub>1L</sub>) / (V<sub>2H</sub> - V<sub>2L</sub>)

R<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>(V<sub>1</sub> - V<sub>3</sub> + CV<sub>2</sub> - CV<sub>3</sub>) + R<sub>2</sub>R<sub>1</sub>(V<sub>1</sub> - 2V<sub>3</sub> + CV<sub>2</sub> - CV<sub>3</sub>) - V<sub>3</sub>R<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> = 0

And here I stuck. I've thought I can take an arbitrary R<sub>1</sub> value, approximately satisfying maximum I<sub>1</sub> requirement, then calculate the rest of resistors from there using formulas above. But no matter how I toss the numbers around I am getting either negative R<sub>3</sub> or some values that look OK but in simulation produce different voltages from expected.

I am beginning to suspect two things, first it seems there is only one solution that has definite resistor values. Using arbitrary R<sub>1</sub> throws calculations off. And second, using even 0.1% standard values also affects the result a lot.

Is there simpler method to calculate the resistors?

UPDATE:

I've managed to finish calculations using the formulas above. The hysteresis was calculated for 29.9V and 30.8V thresholds and 200uA quiescent. The final resistance values added to the schematics.

Answer (score 2):

This is only intended to get you moving in the right direction, I'm not going to attempt a full solution.

- Ignore the I<sub>1</sub> limit in the first instance. When you have obtained the resistor ratios, you can scale them up until the current limit is satisfied.
- Note that the two contributions into V3 are almost symmetrical. From the right, you have a voltage source V2 with an output impedance of R4. From the left, you have the R1+R2 scaled down V1 source, with an output impedance of R3 + R1||R2.
- So first, see if you can find a numerical scaling for V1, and values for the two output impedances, that meet the voltage requirements at V3. This reduces the number of resistor values to juggle.
- Then with the V1 scaling and its effective output impedance, find values for R1, R2 and R3.
- You might have been on the right track if you were wrestling with a negative value of R3. What you were trying to do was set a value for R3 + R1||R2, when you had already had R1 and R2 too large, needing R3 to be negative. R3 can be made positive by reducing the values of R1 and R2.
- Now scale up all the resistors to satisfy the current limit.

Comment: Great point re I1 limit! If proportional scaling of all four resistors does not change V3 then the exact values can be adjusted at leisure at the end. I did make R3 positive at some point by increasing R4, but that changed V3. I'll try your suggested approach.

Comment: I am really confused. If I replace R1-R3 with equivalent resistance, I will have simple circuit with two series resistors. Since at all times V1 is much higher than V2, the current I3 always flows in same direction in this circuit. But in simulation when V1 is low enough (V1L) the voltage on R2 is below V2H, and the current I3 changes direction.

Comment: So, R3+R1||R2 did not work for me. In the end I've rearranged the formulas to begin with approximate R4 and work backward from there. Also increased IQ to 200uA to improve noise immunity. I've added the final values to the original schematics.